# How can I add a checkpoint path from Gdrive to continue training in shivamshrirao repo on Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory, stable-diffusion

How to continue training from a checkpoint in shivamshrirao repo on Colab?
Where am I supposed to add the checkpoint path from Gdrive?

`!python3 train_dreambooth.py` 
`--pretrained_model_name_or_path=$MODEL_NAME` 
`--pretrained_vae_name_or_path="stabilityai/sd-vae-ft-mse"` 
`--output_dir=$OUTPUT_DIR` 
`--revision="fp16"` 
`--with_prior_preservation --prior_loss_weight=1.0` 
`--seed=1337` 
`--resolution=512` 
`--train_batch_size=1` 
`--train_text_encoder` 
`--mixed_precision="fp16"` 
`--use_8bit_adam` 
`--gradient_accumulation_steps=1` 
`--learning_rate=0.000001` 
`--lr_scheduler="constant"` 
`--lr_warmup_steps=10000` 
`--num_class_images=10000` 
`--sample_batch_size=1` 
`--max_train_steps=100000` 
`--save_interval=100000` 
`--save_sample_prompt="photo of name man"` 
`--concepts_list="concepts_list.json"`